How should I go about completely decorrelating a digital signal?
So I'm working on real time signal compression, and I need to come up with the best convolution to minimize the entropy of incoming data (which I will then compress), which I understand is achieved by a convolution that decorrelates the data completely (minimizes autocorrelation). I'm also aware some people call this "Signal Whitening" .
As I currently understand it, the continuous version of this problem has been solved, which involves "normalizing" the power spectral density and then applying a reverse Fourier transform. In the discrete case, I believe that the problem lies with approximating this power spectral density distribution given a finite set of datapoints. Do you know of any good techniques that completely decorrelates (or comes very close to it) finite data? Is my assumption correct that this is a solved problem in the continuous case, but has computational issues in the discrete case? Furthermore, would it be fair to assume that calculating the convolution beforehand and using it in new data from the same source would also result in good decorrelation?
I may be wrong in many of my assumptions so far, and for that I apologize. I'm quite new to the field. I would really appreciate any corrections to my knowledge.

I'm closing this question as off-topic because asking for software libraries is not really an on-topic here, and in any event this question is not specific about what would make a good recommendation (are you working in Python? Go? something else?).

@Sycorax I'm currently working in Python but I could change to any language. I'll edit the question so to not ask for library recommendations. Apologies.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Your inquiry might be a better fit on Signal Processing Stack Exchange.
